# Scale Image to Fit ImageButton Height and Maintain Apsect Ratio

Tags: android, android-layout, scale, android-imagebutton

How can I do the above question? The current image appears way too small. I thought I can fix it by making the height to fill_parent and the width to wrap_content but that didn't work out as the width took the size of the original image and not the scaled version. How can I fix this?

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/androidImage"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#4CAF50"
        android:layout_weight="0">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textSample"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="48sp"
            android:padding="20dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mood_white"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="#100FFFFFF"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
insteadof android:scaleType="centerInside"

Comment: still has no difference. the image is still way too small compared to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute

```
android:scaleType="fitXY".
```